# Erro no banco de dados que some quando atualiza a página - SQL server

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, codeigniter

Tenho um sistema feito em CODEIGNITER onde vários usuários acessam simultaneamente, e ultimamente estou recebendo reclamações que em várias páginas do portal, aparece o seguinte erro:

"Não foi possível conectar com seu banco de dados usando as configurações fornecidas"

Parece um erro bem genérico, por isso não sei qual o problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em toda página esse erro aparece aleatoriamente, e sempre indicando o erro em linhas e arquivos diferente, e ele some logo quando a página é atualizada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pesquisei esse erro e encontrei isso: "Está em modo de usuário único e a única conexão disponível já está sendo usado por alguém ou algo mais." mas não sei como resolver, e não sei se tem a ver com o problema.

Arquivo database.php

```
$db['MKTM'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'usuario',
'password' => 'senha',
'database' => 'banco',
'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'development'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```

);

Comment: Por favor rode esse comando e me fale o resultado `SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('TABELA','UserAccess');` aonde tabela é o nome da sua tabela

Comment: O resultado foi: NULL

Comment: está ai um resultado não previsto, eu vou responder com o modo de mudar teste e me fale se resolve.

Comment: usa esse select aqui e vê o numero maximo de conections simultaneas
SELECT *
FROM sys.configurations c
WHERE c.name = 'user connections';

se tiver um numero baixo, pra aumentar é só usar esse comando aqui
EXEC sp_configure 'user connections', 0;
RECONFIGURE

(setando zero ele vai pro default que é o maximo)

Answer (score 0):

Para mudar a configuração de usuários do **SQL-Server**, basta rodar o seguinte comando:

```
ALTER DATABASE DATABASE_NAME
SET MULTI_USER;
GO
```

Caso ocorra algum erro ao executar comando, acusando que um usuário já está logado, derrube o serviços que usem o banco de dados e rode novamente.

[Referencia](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/databases/set-a-database-to-single-user-mode?view=sql-server-2017)

Testa e me fala se funcionou.

Comment: vou testar, mas oq significa mudar pra multi usuário meu banco?

Comment: no caso vai liberar para acesso de múltiplos usuários simultaneamente

Comment: mas usuários do banco, certo? eu só tenho um

Comment: @BeatrizSgavioli vai permitir múltiplas conexões do mesmo usuário,

Comment: certo, fiz aqui mas continuou dando o erro. mas percebi que esse erro aparece quando duas pessoas tentam acessar o site ao mesmo tempo

Comment: Roda novamente `SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('TABELA','UserAccess');` lembre de trocar o tabela pelo nome da sua tabela. e veja se vai retornar algo diferente.

Comment: ainda tá dando NULL

Comment: Simulei um teste aqui ela retorna null quando você digita o nome da tabela errado. :z https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF2at.png veja o print

Comment: que estranho, já escrevi o nome da tabela de todos os jeitos
só o nome, com o dbo na frente, com o nome do banco na frente, entre colchetes... todos dão NULL

Comment: vi aqui e essa função preciso passar o nome do banco e nao da tabela, vou testar

Comment: Agora apareceu "MULTI_USER"

Comment: Mano do céu é Banco eu to escrevendo tabela desculpa

Comment: kkkkkk tudo bem, mas verifiquei aqui e o banco já era multi user =/

Comment: E o problema ainda persiste ?

Comment: @BeatrizSgavioli caso não atualiza a pergunta com o `database.php` pra eu ver como está configurado.

Comment: vou atualizar a pergunta